# Keeps getting the same C++ error

Tags: c++

I have a little C++ question. I keep getting the same error and i don't know what to do about it.

```
vector<wstring> files;

if (ListFiles(L"C:", L"*.txt", files)) {
    for (vector<wstring>::iterator it = files.begin(); it != files.end(); ++it) {

        DoSomethingWithIt(it->c_str(), false);
    }
}
```

Is the code.

And this is the error i get:

> argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPTSTR"

The error is for the it->c_str() part in the code. Does anyone knows how to fix this and make what i want work?

Comment: What is the function definition of `DoSomethingWithIt`?

Comment: `DoSomethingWithIt` is expecting a non-const pointer, but you are providing a const pointer.

Comment: try switching `it->c_str()` to `&((*it)[0])` :)

Comment: @Joker_vD, better do a cast that can be found and explained  in code review, than applying write-only code.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'd have a hard time explaining in code review why I casted `const char*` to `char*`. Besides, `&const_string_variable[0]` yields `const char*`.

Comment: @Joker_vD you are my hero of the day!!! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Joker_vD, you'd have a harder time explaining the result type, over explaining the `DoSomethingWithIt` isn't const correct.

Comment: Do not cast away `const` if you are not absolutely sure you know what you are doing. Fix `DoSomethingWithIt` to take a `const char*`.

Comment: @Zulan, judging by the signature, it seems like WinAPI function. Not an easy fix to make.

Comment: Although one *can* always make a wrapper the creates a non-const copy before calling `DoSomethingWithIt`, if there is reason to suspect foul-play.

Comment: I have no knowledge of WinAPI in particular, but if a an API requests a non-const string, it probably wants to modify it. At least C++98 forbids to modify the contents of `c_str`, doing so will invite the nasal demons to haunt you. In C++11 it is still `const`, casting it away will again haunt you.

Comment: @Zulan, You'd be wrong on that assumption with the WinAPI. It isn't const correct to 100%, sadly. But I do agree with you in principle on const correctness.

Comment: For the record, we require a [MCVE] here.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `DoSomethingWithIt` has signature `void DoSomethingWithIt(LPTSTR, BOOL)`. In this case, you can do any of the following:

1. Modify `DoSomethingWithIt()` to accept `LPCTSTR` (which is typedef for `const char*` or `const wchar_t*`) instead of `LPTSTR`. This may not be feasible if `DoSomethingWithIt()` is out of your control, or actually needs to modify the buffer you passed into it.
2. Modify your calling site to pass `wchar_t*` instead of `const wchar_t*` by forcefully casting the `const` modifier away with C-style cast:

   ```
   DoSomethingWithIt((LPWSTR)it->c_str(), false);
   ```

   or with `const_cast` operator of C++, specifically designed for this usage:

   ```
   DoSomethingWithIt(const_cast<wchar_t*>(it->c_str()), false);
   ```

   This opens a whole can of worms which may or may not crawl under you skin and eat your internal organs without you noticing it until it's too late, so I would advise against it. One day the way you obtain `files` may change and your `it` will become a const iterator, and if `DoSomethingWithIt()` actually may modify the buffer you passed into it, and it will end in undefined behaviour.
3. Modify your calling site to pass `wchar_t*` instead of `const wchar_t*` by somehow asking the string for the `wchar_t*` pointer to its first character. One way would be this:

   ```
   std::wstring& str = *it;
   DoSomethingWithIt(&str[0], false);
   ```

   or if you prefer more condensed and cryptic style, like this:

   ```
   DoSomethingWithIt(&((*it)[0]), false);
   ```

   Another way to do the same is to use `&*str->begin()` instead of `&str[0]` or `&*(it->begin())` instead of `&((*it)[0])`. However, I personally would consider this last way to be too cryptic for my taste.

   This may lead to changes of the elements of `files` vector, if `DoSomethingWithIt()` may actually modify the buffer you passed into it which may or may not be acceptable to you. However, if later you will change your code in such a way that `it` becomes a const iterator, the compiler will actually detect it and will complain with exactly the same error it complains now, which would allow you to re-think the code and perhaps use the next snippet.
4. Modify your calling site to pass `wchar_t*` instead of `const wchar_t*` by copying the contents of `*it` string into an array of `wchar_t`s (of sufficient length), and the pass the pointer to its first element to `DoSomethingWithIt`:

   ```
   std::wstring temp = *it;
   DoSomethingWithIt(&temp[0], false);
   ```

   or

   ```
   std::vector<wchar_t> temp(it->begin(), it->end());
   temp.push_back(0); // Don't forget the trailing NUL char
   DoSomethingWithIt(&temp[0], false);
   ```

   This way, the contents `files` are guaranteed to not change, but it may or may not lead to a slight performance penalty compared to previous solutions. I also have to add that the last way (with the temporary vector) is the most reliable of all, because technically, in C++03, `std::wstring` is not obliged to store its data in a contiguous block. However, since such implementations are almost unheard of and C++11 mandates that `std::wstring` has store its data in a contigous block, this is not a large concern.

   If you want to use this solution, but also keep changes that `DoSomethingWithIt()` made with the buffer in your `files` (provided it didn't overflow the buffer and kept it null-terminated!), you'll have to add something like this after the `DoSomethingWithIt()` call:

   ```
   it->assign(&temp[0], &temp[0] + wcslen(&temp[0]));
   ```

   .